# Numpy Neural Network with two outputs using two different activation functions

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm want to create a neural network using numpy that has two groups of outputs using different activation functions, like the image below.

[image]

I use an auxiliary `Layer` class to handle the amount of nodes and the activation of that particular layer

```
class Layer():
    def __init__(self,nodes,activation):
        self.nodes = nodes
        self.activation = activation
```

Then I have a `NeuralNetwork` class that loads the layers and has the option to load the weights from a `numpy` array. I'm having trouble to modify the `NeuralNetwork` class to achieve this.

This is the `NeuralNetwork` class:

```
class NeuralNetwork(ActivationFunctions):
    def __init__(self,layers,seed=None):
        self.layers = {}
        self.total_weights = 0
        self._module_to_use = np.random
        self.seed = seed
        inputs = layers[:-1]
        outputs = layers[1:]
        
        for ins,outs in zip(inputs,outputs):
            self.total_weights += ins.nodes*outs.nodes
            layer = self._generate_wt(ins.nodes,outs.nodes)
            activation = outs.activation
            self.layers[len(self.layers)] = {
                'layer':layer,
                'activation':activation
            }
        
        
    def load_layers_from_numpy(self,numpy_layer):
        if isinstance(numpy_layer,list):
            numpy_layer = np.array(numpy_layer)
        prev_use = 0
        layers_dim = self.export_layers_dim()
        for idx,(dim_a,dim_b) in enumerate(layers_dim):
            self.layers[idx]['layer'] = numpy_layer[prev_use:prev_use + dim_a*dim_b].reshape(dim_a,dim_b)
            prev_use = dim_a*dim_b

    def load_layers(self,layers):
        self.layers = {}
        for layer in layers:
            self.layers[len(self.layers)] = {
                'layer':layer['layer'],
                'activation':layer['activation']
            }

    def export_layers_dim(self):
        dims = np.empty(shape=(len(self.layers),2),dtype=np.int32)
        for i in range(dims.shape[0]):
            x,y = self.layers[i]['layer'].shape
            dims[i][0] = x
            dims[i][1] = y
        return dims

    def export_layers(self):
        dim = np.empty(shape=len(self.layers),dtype=object)
        for i in range(dim.shape[0]):
            dim[i] = self.layers[i]
        return dim
    
    def _generate_wt(self,x,y):
        return self._module_to_use.random(size=(x,y))

    def f_forward(self,x):
        # hidden
        for layer in self.layers.values():
            activation = getattr(self,layer['activation'])
            layer = layer['layer']
            z = x.dot(layer)
            z = activation(z)
            x = z
        return z
```

So, for example, an instantiation of this neural network would be:

```
layers = [(24,10,6),(None,'relu','softmax')]
layers = [Layer(node,act) for node,act in zip(*layers)]
nn = NeuralNetwork(layers)
```

How should I modify the `NeuralNetwork` class or the `Layer` class in order to achieve this and still be able to load the weights from a single numpy array?